# The argument type 'Future<dynamic>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'double'

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to get data from Firestore and the data type is a number. I want to assign it to a double variable in my code. Here is the Firestore methods.

```
Future getPercentage(FirebaseUser user, String packageCode) async{
await users.document(user.uid).collection('myPackages').document(packageCode).get().then((doc) {
  return  doc.data['percentCompleted'];

    });
```

}
}

So the returned value from get() 'percentCompleted' is a number and I am trying to assign to a double variable 'percent',

```
percent:  _db.getPercentage(user, packageCode),
```

then i get the above error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the function `getPercentage(user, packageCode)` returns a `Future`, `percent:  _db.getPercentage(user, packageCode)` should use async-await to handle asynchronous values.

You can modify your `getPercentage` function as follows (just cleaning up a bit)-

```
Future<double> getPercentage(FirebaseUser user, String packageCode) async {
  var doc = await users
      .document(user.uid)
      .collection('myPackages')
      .document(packageCode)
      .get();
  // check if snapshot has data here and validate
  return double.parse(doc.data['percentCompleted']);
}
```

And then when calling the `getPercentage(user, packageCode)`, declare the function containing the line `percent:  _db.getPercentage(user, packageCode)`as `async` and then update this code as follows -

```
percent: await _db.getPercentage(user, packageCode),
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

`_db.getPercentage` returns Future so you'll have to `await` for the value

```
await _db.getPercentage(user, packageCode)
```

or you can use .then

```
_db.getPercentage(user, packageCode).then((value){
   ...
})
```

I suggest you go through basics of async programming.